# What is the extra 5 bytes in front of the grpc request and response

Tags: tensorflow, grpc, tensorflow-serving

I am using [tensorflow-serving](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/tree/master/tensorflow_serving/apis) for deep learning model server, it is a grpc serivce. And in order to track the server's requests and responses, there is a proxy in the middle of the server and client. The proxy will record the whole http level requests and responses.

The (request, response) tuple need some way to be human readable. So I need to translate the grpc request and response to json format. As I have the `*.proto` files it looks not so hard. But after some tests, I found that the grpc request and response body shows 5 (different) extra bytes data in front of the whole body.

```
// bytes in the grpc response:
\x00\x00\x00\x00c\nA\n\x07Softmax\x126\x08\x01\x12\x08\x12\x02\x08\x01\x12\x02\x08\n*(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x1e\n\x07default\x12\x02\x08\x01\x1a\x0fserving_default

// bytes in the raw .pb format:
\nA\n\x07Softmax\x126\x08\x01\x12\x08\x12\x02\x08\x01\x12\x02\x08\n*(\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x1e\n\x07default\x12\x02\x08\x01\x1a\x0fserving_default
```

You can see there are extra five bytes `\x00\x00\x00\x00c` there. So...what is this mean? Does all the grpc requests and responses have this extra? Or is there some better way to parse grpc contents and tranlate into some human readable structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gRPC has a 5 byte header. Search for Length-Prefixed-Message in  https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/PROTOCOL-HTTP2.md.

Comment: Thanks for this import link, my fault for not making a good search.